# How to integer data in each tile for each date automatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have some data that is store with sharedpref

like that :

```
2020-10-18,data1:aaaaaa,
2020-10-18,data2:bbbbb,
2020-10-18,data3:cccc,
2020-10-18,data4:ddddd,
2020-10-18,data5:1,
2020-10-18,data6:1.0

2020-10-19,data1:eeee,
2020-10-19,data2:ffff,
2020-10-19,data3:gggg,
2020-10-19,data4:hhhhh,


2020-10-20,data1:iiiii,
2020-10-20,data2:jjjjj,
2020-10-20,data5:1,
```

My goal is to build timeline of even with this data and display a tile with data information for each date.

For exemple if user add data1, data2 and data5 only the 2020-10-20 I search to display a card with only this three data.

What I can do currently

```
1°) at the initState, launch getall(); to generate a string with all key values saved
2°) use regex to match all keys and values for one date 
3°) display these data on a static card
```

What I search

```
1°) at the initState, launch getall(); to generate a string with all key values saved
2°) use regex to match all keys and values for all date 
3°) display in a list all data for each dates ( I can't, or don't know if it's possible)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is sorted by date

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class DataModel {
  const DataModel(this.key, this.value, this.dateTime);
  final String key;
  final String value;
  final DateTime dateTime;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DataModel> dataList = [];
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('y-M-d');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var uuid = Uuid();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 1000) {
      dataList.add(DataModel('data$i', uuid.v4().substring(0, 8),
          DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day + i)));
      dataList.add(DataModel('data${i + 1}', uuid.v4().substring(0, 8),
          DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day + i)));
      dataList.add(DataModel('data${i + 2}', uuid.v4().substring(0, 8),
          DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day + i)));
      i += 3;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var data = dataList[index];
          if (index == 0 || dataList[index - 1].dateTime != data.dateTime) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 4.0),
                  child: Text(dateFormat.format(data.dateTime)),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(data.key),
                  subtitle: Text(data.value),
                )
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data.key),
              subtitle: Text(data.value),
            );
          }
        },
        itemCount: dataList.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]